# Differences between MIPI-CSI1 and MIPI-CSI2

Tags: camera, input

I'm trying to find what makes a difference between MIPI-CSI1 and MIPI-CSI2.

From what I understand on this [specifications document](http://mipi.org/specifications/camera-interface), they both work the same way, except that MIPI-CSI2 offers up to four data pairs, while MIPI-CSI1 offers only one.

Is this correct?

Comment: The block diagrams on that page look pretty explicit to me - one has 1 data pair, the other has *up to* 4 data pairs. Everything else looks the same (physically - no mention is made of data format).

Comment: Well, i'm concerned about the data format actually. Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: I guess the data format itself may be down to the manufacturer of the camera module - it would be dependant on resolution, bit depth, compression, that kind of thing. It may not be "set in stone".

Comment: There is some relevant info here: https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-96385

Answer (score 1):

The lanes are defined at the physical layer (PHY), and are not limited in CSI-2:

*"CSI-2 over C/D-PHY imaging interface does not limit the number of lanes per link. Transmission rate linearly scales with the number of lanes for both C-PHY and D-PHY."*

No only that but CSI-2 defines more than one PHY:

*"C-PHY 1.0, D-PHY v1.2  or “combo C/D-PHY” possible"*

All of that is irrelevant at the protocol level.  The lanes simply increase bandwidth.